# Collections of points maximally spaced with respect to one another

Tags: discrete-geometry, lattices, euclidean-geometry, spherical-geometry

The icosahedron and dodecahedron are well known to share symmetry groups. This partially accounts for the fact that one can form a type of compound  of the two where each of the vertices in the icosahedron are the points, on the same sphere as the vertices of the dodecahedron, which are at a maximal distance from the vertices of the dodecahedron (and similarly the other way around). This fact is easy to see from the image below.

$\hspace{50 mm}$ [image]

Is there a reference which shows that this is also true for the $E_6$ and $E_6^{*}$ minimal vectors, and the $E_7$ and $E_7^{*}$ minimal vectors (both appropriately scaled to lie on the same sphere)? All of these configurations show up in a few interesting contexts, and it is expected that this has been observed a few times before.

**Edit:** It would be interesting to see a general method of solving these types of problems if a reference is not available for the other two configurations of points.